# What is the complexity for the following python code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math

# for loop includes k/2 (ie. if k/2 = 3.5, then i will go from [1, 3]. 1,2, and 3
def pow(x,k):
    y =1
    m = math.trunc(k/2)
    if k == 0:
        return 1
    for i in range(1,m+1):
        y = y * x
    if(k%2 == 0):
        return y * y
    else:
        return y*y*x
```

I think it uses O(1) memory and O(log k) steps. Is it correct?

Comment: converted to python

Answer (score 0):

The memory complexity is correct thus O(1).

The runtime complexity should be O(k). Each line is done in constant time except the for loop. You iterate in your for loop at most k/2 times. This means that the number of iteration will be linear in k. Note that O(k/2) = O(k).

Also you could see that the complexity of log(k) does not work. If k = 16, your loop will iterate 8 times and by taking the log (base 2) we would only obtain 4 times.

Comment: I am trying to make it O(log k) steps but with O(1) memory at the same time but it seems impossible to me. Pretty new to complexity. Would appreciate any help. I thought of recursion but that gives me O(log k) memory. Thank you.